# stdafx.h: fatal error: afxwin.h: No such file or directory (Works for 2018 VS community but not VS code)

Tags: c++, go, visual-studio-code, swig, stdafx.h

I read up on a lot on this issue from other posts but I cant find anything specific to my situation.

I have a large project in C++ that complies successfully in VS 2017 community. I am wrapping the same project in Go using SWIG through the program VS code.

Now i get the error over line 1 in Go, "package main"

```
# _/C_/Users/daramsey/Desktop/GoWrapC/CameraFinal/CameraFinal
In file included from ConnectionRecovery.h:2:0,
             from ConnectionRecovery.cpp:1:
stdafx.h:38:64: fatal error: afxwin.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.(undefined)
```

ConnectionRecovery.h looks like this:

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "PvBaseLib.h"
#include "PvBuffer.h"
#include "PvBufferLib.h"
#include "PvSystem.h"
#include "PvTypes.h"

class ConnectionRecoveryApp
{
public:

    ConnectionRecoveryApp();
    ~ConnectionRecoveryApp();

    void startCamera(PvString mConnectionID);
    uint16_t * retrieveDataPointerPerBuffer(PvPipeline* mPipeline);
    void stopCamera();
    vector<PvString>  vectorOfCameras();

private:

    PvString mConnectionID;
    PvDevice* mDevice;
    PvStream* mStream;
    PvPipeline* mPipeline;

    int mHeight = 512;
    int mWidth = 640;
    bool mbSaveAsCSV;

};
```

Inside my stdafx.h file (which is included header file in project), I find

```
 #include <afxwin.h>         // MFC core and standard components
 #include <afxext.h>         // MFC extensions
 #include <afxdisp.h>        // MFC Automation classes
 #include <afxdhtml.h>
 #include <afxmt.h>
```

When i hit F12 key with my mouse hovering over afxwin.h, I am able to open the contents of the file. Therefore I am assuming that the code should not having an issue with opening the file.

This is the json file for VS Code

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.17763.0",
        "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
}
```

What is the issue? Let me know if you need elaboration.

Comment: ***What is the issue?*** I think you are missing a compiler include path for `MFC` in your Visual Studio Code settings.

Comment: @drescherjm do you know how I can access this?

Comment: Before you put too much effort into this, are you using precompiled headers? If not, you may want to remove stdafx.h entirely.

Comment: Without stdafx.h, i get numerous errors in my program so i assume that i am using precompiled headers

Comment: No i am not using .pch files